# Django form with fileupload

Tags: django, django-forms, django-file-upload

I'm hitting my head against the wall with uploading a file through a form. When uploading through the admin everything works fine. When using a modelform it reloads the form with the filefield blank and the error message "This field is required."

This is the Model

```
class DefaultPage(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
edited_date =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)
parent_page = models.ForeignKey("self",blank=True, null=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,editable=False,blank=True)
def __unicode__ (self): 
    return self.title
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(DefaultPage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class LearningObject(DefaultPage):
archivefile = models.FileField(upload_to='static/learningobject/archivefiles/%Y/%m/%d')
indexpath = models.CharField(max_length=254,editable=False)
def unpackarchive(self):
    archive = self.archivefile
    filename = os.path.basename(str(archive))

    folder = str(filename).split(".")[0]
    print folder
    index_found = "False"
    with zipfile.ZipFile(archive,"r") as z:
        for each in z.namelist():
            if each == "index.html" or each == "index.htm":
                index_found = "True"
            else:
                pass
        if not index_found:
            print "zip file does not contain a valid index.html file"
        else:
            path = os.path.join("static","learningobject","unpackedarchives",folder)
            z.extractall(path)
            self.findindex(path)
def findindex(self,path):

    print path
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'index.ht*'):
            print filename
            self.indexpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
    print self.indexpath

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.unpackarchive()
    super(LearningObject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And this is the view

```
def learningobject_form(request, parent_page_id):
print 
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = LearningObjectForm()
else:
    form = LearningObjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        learningobject = request.FILES['archivefile']
        title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        parent_page = DefaultPage.objects.get(pk=parent_page_id)
        post = Page.objects.create(archivefile=learningobject,title=title,parent_page=parent_page)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index', ))
return render(request, 'wiki/learningobject_form.html', {'form': form,})
```

and this is the form

```
class LearningObjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = LearningObject
    fields = ['title','archivefile']
```

and the template

```
<form action='' method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
```

Comment: Do you have: enctype="multipart/form-data" in your html form tag? I mean, does your form tag looks something like: <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">...</form> ?

Comment: no... no it does not! I've just added the template above. What you are saying is that I should edit <form action='' method='post'> to  be  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">

Comment: I noticed that your <form> tag isn't closed. You'd better close it :-)

Comment: Thanks @dizpers in the real thing it was. It is just further down the page. It is all working now.